# How to Modify Path temporarily when starting Visual Studio Code

Tags: path, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I'm working on a Windows machine without admin access. Is it possible to modify the  path variable when I start Visual Studio Code (a launch configuration setting per?) to modify the path for the duration that VS Code is running? So for instance, if I need to add python to the path:

```
$env:path="$env:Path; C:\SomeDir\Python\3.5.2\python3.exe"
```

Can I run this somewhere so that if I open a terminal in VS Code I will have the python command recognised on the path?